# Function in Excel VBA needs to refresh automatically when workbook is opened

Tags: excel, vba, function

**Here is my function:**

```
Function UserID()

Application.Volatile True
UserID = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

End Function
```

This needs to update with the new username of whoever opened the file but sometimes it does not update unless you click in a random cell and press enter. I've already tried application.volatile and that doesn't help. I have also tried the code below and that doesn't work either. I need help!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheets("Home").Calculate
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` instead of  just `Sheets("Home").Calculate`?

Answer (score 0):

What if to add a piece of code which changes the value of some cell (better, unused) and then returns the previous value? From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile):

> The function will be recalculated when any cell in any workbook in the application window changes value.